# Schengen Question - Dual EU/US citizenship but only US passport

Tags: dual-nationality, 90-180-visa-rules

My dad is a dual US/Greece citizen but only travels with his US passport. Whenever he comes to Europe, he always has his Greek national ID card but presents his US passport and gets a Schengen entry stamp. My question is, is he still subject to the 90/180 day rule because he entered on an American passport or does it not apply because he is an EU citizen? Is he legally required to get a Greek passport and enter on that?

Answer (score 4):

> is he still subject to the 90/180 day rule because he entered on an American passport

No.  He's an EU citizen regardless of what document he used to cross the border.

> or does it not apply because he is an EU citizen?

That is correct.

> Is he legally required to get a Greek passport and enter on that?

Probably not.  He can always enter on his Greek national ID.  Or he can continue to use his US passport, and if the 90/180 rule ever becomes an issue, he can show his Greek ID at that point to show that it doesn't apply to him.

Comment: (+1) this is indeed the correct answer. I would like to add some context, I am also an EU/non-EU double citizen and I have entered the Schengen are a few times with my non-EU passport. I always also show my EU ID with the non-EU passport and never get the passport stamped. I think it's always good to show proof of EU citizenship to border control to avoid any unnecessary headaches or bureaucracy later (especially if you plan to stay more than 90 days or have frequent entries).